# Showing temporary data in a WebView

Tags: c#, webview, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm trying to make an application that basically takes a .zip file (using a `FileOpenPicker`), extracts the .zip file (in a subfolder of `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder`) and tries to read one of the HTML page that was extracted.

Apprently, the `WebView` can't load any web pages from ApplicationData:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781215.aspx

`Note that, for security reasons, you cannot navigate to HTML you have downloaded to this location and you cannot run any executable or potentially executable code, such as script or CSS. It is intended for media such as images or videos and the like.`

There is a method called [NavigateToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.navigatetostring.aspx) in the `WebView`, so I could load the .html file in memory and navigate to it. The only problem is, if the webpage references images, css or links to other pages within the zip, I'm screwed. I don't quite understand why they don't allow this when you can use NavigateToString to do whatever you want... anyway...

Is there any workaround to achieve what I want?

Comment: Have you tried putting the html into a string, deleting the old html file and then creating a new one with the same content?

Answer (score 0):

The workarround is to insert everything (javascript, css, images as base64 encoded strings) into the html and pass it to NavigateToString. Depending on the webpage, it could be achievable or almost imposible. I'm doing this myself in an App because it is the only way I have found.